# Does Apex save strings that are entirely whitespace as null?

Tags: apex, custom-field, string

I have an Apex class and I recently discovered that passing a string comprised of just 10 ASC32 chars (ten spaces) up to it, that data gets saved in a Text(255) field as null. Or at least null matches it on a SOQL query. So do those white spaces get lost when saving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apex Code does not, but the underlying database does trim both sides of strings stored in fields, and empty strings are subsequently null. You'll never query for a text field and get an empty string in it. This behavior is consistent with calls made by the API as well as edits in the user interface.